# Express: send response after getting another response via an api call

Tags: node.js

I want my website to respond after a successful api call, which is initiated via a post request and also changes some database values.

If there was NO post request the site should also load as usual.

If I do something like this, then the site is getting loaded as usual and then I get an error because of the second rendering attempt.

I guess because node does wait for the `receipt`, but in parallel does already execute the `loadNewSite()` function:

```
app.all('/customer', function(req, res) {

    if (Object.keys(req.body).length != 0) {
        apiCall(someParameter)
        .on('error', error => {console.log(error);} )
        .on('receipt', function() {loadNewSite();} );
    }  

    function loadNewSite() {
        return res.render('site.html');
    }

    loadNewSite()

})
```

Comment: You're guessing right, but why don't you just remove the last line **loadNewSite()** to avoid send response multiple times?

Comment: Sorry I had not formulated the task clearly, see the edited version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the last loadNewSite() as one is already called when you `on reciept`

check with `req.method` whether it's a `POST` request or not.

```
app.all('/customer', function(req, res) {

    // if method is not post handle seperately
    if(req.method != 'POST'){
        return loadNewSite('site.html');
    }
    if (Object.keys(req.body).length != 0) {
        apiCall(someParameter)
        .on('error', error => {console.log(error);} )
        .on('receipt', function() {loadNewSite();} );
    }  
    function loadNewSite() {
        return res.render('site.html');
    }    
})
```

Comment: Sorry I had not formulated the task clearly, see the edited version

Answer (score 0):

I would create a promise to execute the Api call and resolve it on `receipt` or reject it on `error`. Then make the callback `async` and `await` for the api call promise.

I left the final call to `loadNewSite` in case of error, obviously you can modify it and make a function that maybe returns something different in error case.

```
 const execApiCall = (params) => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     apiCall(params)
    .on('error', error => {reject(error);} )
    .on('receipt', function() {resolve();} );
   }) 
 };

 app.all('/customer', async function(req, res) {

    function loadNewSite() {
      return res.render('site.html');
    }    

    if (Object.keys(req.body).length != 0) {
        try {
          await execApiCall(params);
          return loadNewSite();
        } catch (e) { //handle errors }
    }  

    loadNewSite()

})
```

Comment: Sorry I had not formulated the task clearly, see the edited version